# Do I need to synchronize geofence api calls?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-pendingintent, android-geofence

I need to update the monitored geofences by removing old and setting new list.
Do I need to synchronize these calls?
Is it possible that adding the geofences will run during or before the removing them?

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to achieve (post code you want to execute and expected result)?

The knowledge if methods [addGeofences](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html#addGeofences(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and [removeGeofences](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html#removeGeofences(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) are synchronous is not documented but I can say from my own experience and common sense that **yes** they are synchronous and called in the same thread.

If you simply want to call one after another from the same thread

```
removeGeofences(...);
addGeofences(...);
```

then you don't need to synchronize them.